# Do I say: "Hook me up to this nice party!" or "Hook me up on this nice party!"

Tags: grammar, idioms

Do I say:

> Hook me up to this nice party!

OR

> Hook me up on this nice party!

I am trying to give a connotation that the party sounds good and I want my friend to give me an invitation to go there. Should I say in some other better way?

Answer (score 7):

Normally I think you'd just say "Hook me up!", but if you want to be more explicit, you can say "Hook me up *with* _*_*!" (But I think "Hook me up with an invite!" is more natural than "Hook me up with the party!")

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is too late now, because I sent: Hook me up to some nice events! Well, i guess I will have to use the same excuse again that english is not my native language. :) Does it sound too weird what I said?

Comment: @Richard: Yeah, it sounds pretty weird. In the future, in situations where you're concerned about sounding weird, I'd suggest avoiding slang that you don't feel perfectly confident about. Slang can be tricky, because even things that are *technically* correct can still sound really unnatural. With more standard English, even if you make some non-native-speaker mistakes, I don't think it sounds quite as bad. (And, not just for English. In your native language, imagine a foreigner making mistakes in slang vs. making mistakes in the standard language.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your constructions is fluent. The idiom "Hook me up" should either be used as a complete idiom by itself or to request *means* such as "hook me up with a ticket" or "hook me up with an invite."

Your first sentence:

> Hook me up to this nice party!

would if it means anything mean that you want to be connected to the party like a wire to a stereo or electrical outlet.

Your second sentence:

> Hook me up on this nice party!

seems meaningless to me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound right either way. It's like you're trying too hard to be hip.

Better to say, "May I go to your party?" Or, "Please, invite me to your party!"